# How do you do this in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

I have two columns, Name (Column A) and Amount (Column B).

I was able to compute for the sum of amounts in B of a person who's name is "Lhynne" in column A, which can be done using this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B)
```

Now, I want to compute the total amount accounted for Lhynne and whenever the amount is less than or equal to 30, I'll add two to the amount. What formula can I use for this?

example.

1. Name     | Amount
2. Lhynne   | 30
3. Nica     |  15
4. Lhynne   | 40
5. Lhynne   | 20

So Lhynne's total amount is (30+2) + 40 + (20 + 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer using the array formula found on [this](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/summing_and_counting_using_multiple_criteria/).

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B) + (SUM((A:A="Lhynne")*(B:B<="30"))*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following...

`=IF(SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B)<=30, SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B)+2, SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B))`

Comment: What I meant is that for every cell in column B, I would add 2 whenever the amount is <= 30.

ex. 
Name     | Amount
Lhynne   | 30
Nica       |  15
Lhynne   | 40
Lhynne   | 20

So Lhynne's total amount is (30+2) + 40 + (20 + 2).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are working with a table similar to this:

[image]

If you would like to sum up all cases where column A is "Lhynne" and add 2 every time the amount linked to "Lhynne" in column B is less than or equal to 30, you could use SUMIF plus COUNTIFS. In your case it should be something like this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Lhynne",B:B) + COUNTIFS(A:A, "Lhynne", B:B, "<=30") * 2
```

Practically you sum all values related to "Lhynne" and you count every time your value is "Lhynne" and less than or equal to 30 and add 2.

In case you would like to sum up all values for "Lhynne" in column A, where column B values are more than 30 and just add 2 whenever it is less then or equal to 30 you can do like this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, "Lhynne", B:B, ">30") + COUNTIFS(A:A, "Lhynne", B:B, "<=30") * 2
```

Comment: I think they were looking for a way to add 2 if <=30, otherwise add 0.

Comment: In fact there was an argument too much inside COUNTIFS. Sorry about that! Now I have corrected the formulas in my reply and tested. They work. As I have seen you updated your post, the right answer should be my first formula.

Comment: I'm using MS Excel and it still doesn't work. I'm just getting the total amount without the +2s when the amount is less than or equal to 30.

Comment: I checked and there was a bracket too much in the conditions (it was ">30)", while it is correct as ">30"), so if you copied and pasted my formula it did not work. Now I have fixed my typo and it should be ok! Keep it as alternative to the other solution you found by yourself!